# Email Header Analyzer

Tags: php, email

Don't vote down for my Question.

I'm creating tool like on this page http://www.iptrackeronline.com/email-header-analysis.php for analyzing the email headers.

I'm getting Ip address of the user using regular Expression. But There are lot's of ip address in 'Received' header section, I want to ignore all others ip address and get the user original ip address.

Sample Email Header: IP - 70.183.59.6

```
Return-path: <user@example.com>
Received: from mac.com ([10.13.11.252])
  by ms031.mac.com (Sun Java System Messaging Server 6.2-8.04 (built Feb 28
  2007)) with ESMTP id <0JMI007ZN7PETGC0@ms031.mac.com> for user@example.com; Thu,
  09 Aug 2007 04:24:50 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from mail.dsis.net (mail.dsis.net [70.183.59.5])
  by mac.com (Xserve/smtpin22/MantshX 4.0) with ESMTP id l79BOnNS000101
  for <user@example.com>; Thu, 09 Aug 2007 04:24:49 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from [192.168.2.77] (70.183.59.6) by mail.dsis.net with ESMTP
  (EIMS X 3.3.2) for <user@example.com>; Thu, 09 Aug 2007 04:24:49 -0700
Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2007 04:24:57 -0700
From: Frank Sender <sender@example.com>
Subject: Test
To: Joe User <user@example.com>
Message-id: <61086DBD-252B-46D2-A54C-263FE5E02B41@example.com>
MIME-version: 1.0 (Apple Message framework v752.2)
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.752.2)
Content-type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII; format=flowed
Content-transfer-encoding: 7bit
```

If you know any email parser which can fetch the ip address , then give me link.

Comment: Use a regular expression to tease apart the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think this is easier without regex: these headers are organized as lines, so iterate over the lines from top to bottom and store the lines based on the first word of the line.

`Received:` headers are always in reverse order, ie when reading from top to bottom the last one you'll encounter is the server closest to the sender.  That means that if all you need it that `Received:` record you can just store it as a single entry, overwriting those encountered before.

A last note: if the headers contain an [X-Originating-IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Originating-IP) header, that header will contain the ip address of the actual sender.

Comment: if possible can you send your code here, i am not getting exact what i have to do